# how do i know how many users are online

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect when user leaves a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page)
>   [Check if user closed the page in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992753/check-if-user-closed-the-page-in-php)

i did not find my answer by viewing other question.

As i wanted to make online chat application for my web site

Many answers says that store users status to 1 so that we can identify who is login

on Logut i will make status to 0

yes this is good idea but my confusion is that if someone not logut and close the browser or user's session expire in anyway how do i set status to 0

Comment: This has been asked *many* times before on StackOverflow.

Comment: yes i know but it can no gave my answer

Comment: @richsage if
 you know this has been many times so provide me link here

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992753/check-if-user-closed-the-page-in-php), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887919/how-to-detect-if-the-user-is-logout-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/324675/help-needed-please-update-database-on-browser-close.  I think this is what you are after.

Comment: ok but this also calls when user changes page

Answer (score 0):

Make the server ping the client regularly.