# Logout issues in a single-user system

Tags: php, sql-update, logout, single-user

I've been asked to build a project management application that could only host **one user at a time**. I managed to do that by simply creating a `status` row in my `user` table which is set to 1 when somebody is logged in.

Now, `status = 1`, nobody else can log in, they get an error message instead saying that another user is already using the application. When the online user logs out, I update the `status` row in the database and set it to 0 in order to allow other users to log in freely.

Everything is working just fine except, as you can see, it relies on the logout button and many users forget to logout that way, they just close the tab or the browser leaving `status` as 1 and then blocking the whole system.

I tried a few methods to update the database on page close with session timeout or via `onunload` but I couldn't reach a clean and reliable way of doing so.

How could I develop such a system combining single-user mode and auto/smart logout at the same time?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992753/check-if-user-closed-the-page-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this is by checking whether the logged in user has been active in the last X minutes. Check this when the new user tries to log in. When the previous user has been inactive for that period, unset the status in the database and let the new user in. You should then also invalidate the session of the previous user, in case he comes back.

Don't try to detect session endings.

Comment: I get the idea, but what if the user closed the browser? That's my problem. I can't check if he is active or not since the session has been destroyed, but the `status` value is still set to 1.

Comment: That's why you should log user activity. You can insert a record in an activity table in the database every time the user makes a new request. When another user tries to login, you validate whether the last time an event has occurred is X minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

You could `reduce the user's Session timeout`. I think you can accomplish that both from `Php` and the `Webserver` (Apache, IIS, ..), should really look at the man pages. That done, you could realize a `polling system` which periodically ping the user to verify his/her presence. For example, you could make a client-side `Ajax script` which pings the site at fixed intervals, so that would prolong the user's active Session. If the user doesn't ping the site anymore, after the time-window has expired, then set his/her `status = 0`.
That is just an idea. Try searching more about on Google.

---

A variant: you could set a cookie from the server-side language, and associate the session with that cookie. So, give it a short expire time. Then make a client script which periodically send a hidden request to the server. When the server receives the request, it re-write the cookie again, so the new time will start again from the beginning.